# Avoid table rebuild when adding or removing a column?

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-data-tools

Adding or removing a column using SQLPAckage (SSDT) causes the table to be rebuilt. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: AFAIK dropping a column always requires a rebuild.

Answer (score 2):

If you're adding a column anywhere but the end of the table, that will definitely trigger a table rebuild. You shouldn't see you table rebuilding otherwise. You may want to try a Schema Compare to see what SSDT thinks is going to change. That would show you the differences it sees and could give you more insight into why your table is being rebuilt.

This is not normally the case. It could be triggered by a change in collation, but should otherwise just use an ALTER TABLE command.